# Int list to int OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I am new to OCaml, so I am learning the basics. I am writing a function that determines whether a list contains a given integer.

```
let rec int_member (x: int) (l: int list) : bool 
begin match l with
| [] -> false
| hd :: rest -> x = hd || int_member rest x
end
```

as a test case...

```
let test (): bool =
(int_member 1 [1;2;3]) = true
;; run_test "contains 1 [1;2;3]" test
```

I am getting an error saying that "this expression has type int list but an expression was expected of type int". How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at your recursive call, you should see that you're not passing the arguments quite right! Otherwise this code is quite good. (I see a missing `=`, and also using `begin` and `end` isn't very idiomatic OCaml here. You can just leave them out.)

Comment: one other question. with respect to style, is there an alternative way of writing this expression? if (a = k) then b else (assoc k rest)

Answer (score 1):

> int_member rest x

The first argument to `int_member` should be an `int`. You're passing an `int list` as the first argument. That's what the error message is complaining about.

You simply switched around the order of the arguments.

PS: The `begin ... end` in your code is superfluous.